# Bad Image error when trying to run program

Tags: c++, image, console

So I recently finished a VC++ console application I have been working on and I sent it to one of my friends to try out but he cant even open it because he keeps getting an error.

A box will open up with the title **Bad - Image** and then it shows the error and stuff, it says it cant find the file `MSVCP140D.dll` on my friends computer but when I start the program it runs fine.

Can anyone tell me why he cant play the program and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have built your project in debug mode and you are using `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` RunTime library.

- In Visual Studio main menu, select Project -> Properties
- Go to "Configuration Properties" -> C/C++ -> Code Generation
- In Runtime Library, select **`Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`** and rebuild your project.

Alternatively you can build your project in Release mode, then select **`Multi-threaded (/MT)`** Runtime library.

This will make a stand-alone executable file which uses standard windows libraries, you won't have to provide additional dlls with the *.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ship your program with the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package. That's `MSVCP140D.dll`.

As `user4581301` pointed out, the `D` in `MSVCP140D.dll` means 'Debug'.
You shouldn't ship a debug-enabled executable. It makes reverse engineering, hacking, and other modifications easier.
You should instead compile a release build, and ship it with the redistributable.

Comment: Close. In MSVCP140D.dll, the D means OP's compiling a debug build. OP needs to compile and ship the release build and possibly the reditsributable package.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to do one thing(the easy solution), you just go to your `system32` directory at system where you have built the code and find out the file `MSVCP140D.dll`, put it with your executable(.exe) and give it to your friend, and tell him to keep the dll in same folder as the exe.

`MSVCP140D.dll` (redistributable pack) is one of the run time dependencies you need to provide to run your application.

Now it will get installed. Or you can copy the dll at `system32` at target system and then try.

But you shouldn't provide the `debug` build if you are giving it to client, you should provide the release version of it.